# How do I use an if/else statement to determine if a field is filled in?

Tags: templating, entries

I know how to add images into my template:

```
{% set image = entry.featureImage.first() %}
<div class="imagewrapper">
    <img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}" width="{{ image.getWidth('banner') }}" height="{{ image.getHeight('banner') }}">
</div>
```

But what if my client doesn't have feature images for all of his entries? I need some function that'll tell the website, if there is no image, omit `<div class="imagewrapper">`.

Perhaps some kind of if/else statement that I can use:

```
{% if
    //the featureimage for this entry is filled in
%}
    {% set image = entry.featureImage.first() %}
    <div class="imagewrapper">
        <img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}" width="{{ image.getWidth('banner') }}" height="{{ image.getHeight('banner') }}">
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`length`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/length.html) Twig filter for that.

```
{% if entry.featureImage | length %}
    {% set image = entry.featureImage.first() %}
    <div class="imagewrapper">
       <img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}" width="{{ image.getWidth('banner') }}" height="{{ image.getHeight('banner') }}">
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

If there isn't an image in `featureImage` then nothing will be output.